# Angular 2 return datas with conditions

Tags: angular

New in Angular 2.

I wondering to know how to return datas with condition as simply as possible using Angular2.

```
getCreancesByHero() {
  this.creanceService.getCreancesByHero()
    .then( creances => this.creances = creances )
    .catch(error => this.error = error);
}
```

I just would like to sort only "creances" which are owned by Hero.
The hero.value is get from :

```
onSelect(hero: Hero, event: any) {
  event.stopPropagation();
    this.value = hero.id
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
```

I tried using TrackingBy or pipes, but it didn't help.

thanks
Bea

Comment: Define "return datas with condition". What is creances, and what do you want to achieve, precisely?

Comment: I have a 2 datasDB (using In-Memory-data) and would like to join them using a id. 
For exemple :   let heroes = [ { id: 1, type: 2 }, ... ], let creance = [ { id: 1, id_hero: 1}, ... ] - 
First, I have listed the hero with 
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero, $event)">
then I would like to show (on-click) the creances attached/refered by id_hero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to display the creances of the selected hero. That doesn't have much to do with angular, but rather to plain old JavaScript:

```
onSelect(hero: Hero, event: any) {
  // ...
  this.creancesOfSelectedHero = this.creances.filter(c => c.id === hero.id);
}
```

And in the view, you can use a second ng-repeat to display these creances:

```
<div *ngFor="let creance of creancesOfSelectedHero">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I will try. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks again. I have exported => creancesOfSelectedHero: Creance[]; But why "c => c" ?

Comment: This is a lamda expression, it's (almost)  equivalent to `function(c) { return c.id === hero.id }`you can choose whatever argiment name you want